# Convert RichTextBox text into PdfPCell from PdfPTable

Tags: html, pdf, itext, rtf

I have a WPF `RichTextBox` Control from which I retrieve a string formatted as HTML. I would like to add the contents of this string to a `PdfPCell` (and add this cell to a `PdfPTable`). But I don't succeed in creating a PDF in a way that string is formatted, containing bullets, numbering, indentation, alignment and so on.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an example that results in what you are currently getting?  It's easier for us to work off of your existing code than to create a completely different method.  This is the case even if the original code doesn't work.

Comment: You say "rtf html string" which is confusing, which is is, "rtf" or "html"?

Comment: The problem with the terminology of RTF and HTML is that Adobe has defined a format that is a subset of HTML that is called "rich text". It has nothing in common with the "Rich Text Format" we know as RTF. This being said: there's a solution for the problem, but I have a day full of meetings ahead, so I can't answer the question.

Comment: Actually, this question may be a duplicate of [Add a rich Textbox to PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015644/add-a-rich-textbox-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: This link fixed your problem ???

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745277/parsing-html-snippets-and-adding-to-pdfptable